# Error code list for vfs_mount for OpenStep 4.2 (BSD 4.3/Mach)

Tags: bsd, vfs

**(Background, This is not the question)** I'm having trouble installing OpenStep 4.2 (Intel) on my old laptop, It's because it can't find a OpenStep root image (which I understand) here is the error.

```
hc0: Resetting drives...
rootdev 30f, howto 3
vfs_mountroot: error=6
panic: (Cpu 0) vfs_mountroot: cannot mount root
panic: NeXT Mach 4.2: Wed Apr 16 13:44:57 PDT 1997; root(rcbuilder):Objects/mk-183.34.obj~2/RELEASE_I386

System Panic:
vfs_mountroot: cannot mount root
```

**Question, I am interested in the errors on the following two lines**

```
rootdev 30f, howto 3
vfs_mountroot: error=6
```

I have checked [/kernel/bsd/vfs/vfs_subr.c](https://github.com/RhapsodiOS/Kernel/blob/22ad0c8485691fcee31e57117a62a3e338868811/kernel/bsd/vfs/vfs_subr.c#L286) but I can't figure out what error `howto 3` and `rootdev 30f` (BIOS HDD is 0x80 ?? BIOS Floppy is 0x00 ?) and the error 6.

Is there a list anywhere?

Thanks